# Getting error while starting nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am using nginx server for my rails application. If i start nginx in my server the following error is comming.

```
$ sudo service nginx start
  Starting nginx (via systemctl):  Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
  [FAILED]
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: To see what is causing the error, you should have a look at nginx's logs: `sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: Have you done any of the recommendations from the message? What have you found?

Comment: Error output of `nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` might give you some hints at what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Hey so related to the first comment: if you use `sudo nginx -t` it will give the line and error that is making the nginx.conf file fail to load.